# count of specific values after groupby in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of pairwise variables and would like to get the counts of

**Example data**

```
df = data.frame(Subject = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), 
                 Variable_1 = c("A","A","B","A","A","B"),
                 Variable_2 = c("B","C","C","B","C","C"),
                 Value = c(1,-1,0,1,0,1))
```

which looks like this

```
Subject Variable_1 Variable_2     Value 
    1      A             B          1
    1      A             C          -1
    1      B             C          0
    2      A             B          1
    2      A             C          0
    2      B             C          1
```

**Desired outome**

I would like to obtain a dataframe which contains each pair of variables and the number of times each value occurs in the whole dataframe. The end result should look something like this :

```
Variable 1     Variable 2     Count_0      Count_1     Count_-1
A                  B            2             0            0
A                  C            1             0            1
B                  C            1             1            0
```

The code below sort of gets close to what I'm looking for, but isnt quite there (and I'm sure there is a more elegant/programmatic  way). If someone would be able to help, that would be fantastic.

```
df2 = df %>% select(Variable_1, Variable_2, Value) %>%
      group_by(Variable_1, Variable_2) %>%
      tally(direction == 0)
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::pivot_wider` for this -

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = Value, values_from = Value, 
                   id_cols = c(Variable_1, Variable_2),
                   values_fn = length, names_prefix = 'Count_', values_fill = 0)

#  Variable_1 Variable_2 Count_1 `Count_-1` Count_0
#  <chr>      <chr>        <int>      <int>   <int>
#1 A          B                2          0       0
#2 A          C                0          1       1
#3 B          C                1          0       1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ftable` what will give counts for all possible combinations.

```
ftable(df[-1])
#                      Value -1 0 1
#Variable_1 Variable_2             
#A          B                 0 0 2
#           C                 1 1 0
#B          B                 0 0 0
#           C                 0 1 1
```

Or using `aggregate` with `table` and `as.factor`.

```
aggregate(as.factor(df$Value), df[2:3], table)
#  Variable_1 Variable_2 x.-1 x.0 x.1
#1          A          B    0   0   2
#2          A          C    1   1   0
#3          B          C    0   1   1
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option with `aggregate` + `table` + `factor`

```
aggregate(Value ~ ., df[-1], function(x) table(factor(x, levels = unique(df$Value))))
```

gives

```
  Variable_1 Variable_2 Value.1 Value.-1 Value.0
1          A          B       2        0       0
2          A          C       0        1       1
3          B          C       1        0       1
```